# Why do I have to wrap console.error in a lambda?

Tags: javascript, binding

Consider these two scripts:

**a.js**

```
const main = async () => {
  throw new Error('DESTROY ALL HUMANS');
};

main().catch(error => console.error(error));
```

**b.js**

```
const main = async () => {
  throw new Error('DESTROY ALL HUMANS');
};

main().catch(console.error);
```

**a.js** uses a lambda but **b.js** passes `console.error` directly.

I read somewhere that `console.error.bind(console)` might be required in the case of **b.js**. However, when I run them they both show the same behavior.

How might the behavior of these two differ?

Comment: I think this is just because of the way you are using it. `.catch` is the only thing that requires it be wrapped in an anonymous, callback function. In the case of `a.js` you are just specifying what exactly to do with `error` whereas in `b.js` you are just letting `.catch` know which function to call (that has the same signature as the lambda)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already, read the [documentation on MDN about this topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch). It's pretty thorough. `.catch` is syntactic sugar wrapping a call to `obj.then(undefined, onRejected)`.

> `onRejected`
>   A `Function` called when the Promise is rejected. This function has one argument: `reason` - The rejection reason.

Other than that, I would look into [callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function). `console.error` does not itself require wrapping in a function - just it's use during this Promise-rejection case.

In the case of `b.js`, you are seeing that you can pass the `console.log` function as a [first-class object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions), itself, and `.catch` will know how to treat it, i.e. execute it in response to a rejection passing in `reason` (which is what your `a.js` is defining explicitly).